# Problem with textarea "query_utils.DeferredAttribute" message in empty form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new in Django and i am making a typical CRUD app. In the "add" section, in the comment textarea this message appears "

```
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03B446A0>"
```

and i dont know what to do. I had tried multiples solutions in other stackoverflow questions but i cant find the solutions!

Here's the code

```
class Turno(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    medic = models.ForeignKey('Medic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    observations = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.date} {self.person} {self.medic}' 


def new_turn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        turnFormPost = TurnForm(request.POST)
        if turnFormPost.is_valid():
            turnFormPost.save()
        return redirect("admin_index")
    turnForm = TurnForm(instance=Turno)
    context = {
         'form':turnForm
    }
    return render(request,"turn_new.html", context)


class TurnForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Turno
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'date': DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
            'observations': Textarea(attrs={'rows':5, 'cols':50})
        }

-turn_new.html

    <div class="container">
        <h2>New Turn</h2>
        <form method="POST">   
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{form}}
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'new_turn' %}">Back to index</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the textarea of 'observations' in 'turn_new.html' the message that appears is this

```
"<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03B446A0>"
```